# Actionscript 3.0 Keyboard event listener doesn't call on function or even fire

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, keyboard-events, keylistener

The keyBoard event listeners call on the rotate and unrotate functions and based on the key inputs(A and D) will implement either of the functions and rotate the image or return it to the original upright position. However, I haven't been able to get the function to work. When I press the A or D keys on the keyboard nothing happens. I even put trace() in one of the functions to see if the function will even be implemented but I don't get anything. I put in my Scripts below. Why are the functions not working? Do the eventlisteners fire or are there conflicts? I'm not getting any error messages.

```
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);
    function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
 if(ti.text.search('a')!=-1) load_image("http://i54.tinypic.com/anom5d.png", "ottefct");
 else if(ti.text.search('b')!=-1) load_image("http://i53.tinypic.com/2dv7dao.png", "rnd");
 else if(ti.text.search('c')!=-1) load_image("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png", "ssd");
    }

var loaded_images:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function load_image(url:String, id_name:String)
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.name = id_name;
    var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
    loader.load(url_req);
}

function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var img_name:String = evt.currentTarget.loader.name
    var spr_box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    spr_box.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader);

    spr_box.mouseChildren = false;
    spr_box.doubleClickEnabled = true;

    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    spr_box.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);
    spr_box.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, unrotate);

    spr_box.width = 124;
    spr_box.height = 180;
    spr_box.x = 430;
    spr_box.y = 425;

    this.addChild(spr_box);
    loaded_images[img_name] = spr_box;
}


function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag()
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.stopDrag()
}

function rotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==68) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 90 }
}

function unrotate(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==65) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 0; 
    trace("A key pressed")}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because sprites don't necessarily dispatch keyboard events. Add the listener to the stage instead

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, unrotate);
```

You'll need to keep track of which "spr_box" is selected, I'm guessing you'll do that with a double click. Create a variable called `currentSpr_box`, and then in your listener function, set the  `currentSpr_box` as the currentTarget

```
spr_box.addEventListener(MoustEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, onSelect); //add this when creating spr_box in onLoadingComplete

private function onSelect(event:MouseEvent):void{
   currentSpr_box = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
}
```

In your rotate functions, you need do set `currentSpr_box.rotation`

**Update... full code sample**

```
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);
    function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
 if(ti.text.search('a')!=-1) load_image("http://i54.tinypic.com/anom5d.png", "ottefct");
 else if(ti.text.search('b')!=-1) load_image("http://i53.tinypic.com/2dv7dao.png", "rnd");
 else if(ti.text.search('c')!=-1) load_image("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png", "ssd");
    }

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, unrotate);

var loaded_images:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var currentSpr_Box:Sprite;

function load_image(url:String, id_name:String)
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.name = id_name;
    var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
    loader.load(url_req);
}

function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var img_name:String = evt.currentTarget.loader.name
    var spr_box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    spr_box.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader);

    spr_box.mouseChildren = false;
    spr_box.doubleClickEnabled = true;

    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, onSelect);

    spr_box.width = 124;
    spr_box.height = 180;
    spr_box.x = 430;
    spr_box.y = 425;

    this.addChild(spr_box);
    loaded_images[img_name] = spr_box;
}

function onSelect(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    currentSpr_box = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
}

function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag()
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.stopDrag()
}

function rotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (currentSpr_box != null && evt.keyCode==68)  currentSpr_box.rotation = 90;
}

function unrotate(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (currentSpr_box != null && evt.keyCode==65) currentSpr_box.rotation = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this listener, in onLoadingComplete anywhere? and when I did that, I got an error **1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.**

Comment: okay, get rid of the private, that was just a habbit of mine. You add the keyboard listener before you load the images... or even when your app starts. You add the "spr_box" double click listener when you create the spr_box in the onLoadingComplete

Comment: I got another error, **1119: Access of possibly undefined property currentSpr_box through a reference with static type flash.events:KeyboardEvent.**                                `function rotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==68) {
 evt.currentSpr_box.rotation = 90 }
}

function unrotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==65) {
    evt.currentSpr_box.rotation = 0 }
}`

Comment: Is that how I'm supposed to have the rotate functions?

Comment: currentSpr_box is not part of a keyboard event, so no. Let me just re-write it for you in my answer. You do want this to rotate AFTER you've double clicked the spr_box right?

Comment: Yes. I double click the spr_box and your function should make it the currentTarget, right? and then I can press the A and D keys

Comment: okay... I added the example. Now if you double click an image and press the keyboard key it should work.

Comment: No, the current target is different for every kind of event and its usually what dispatched the event. For a keyboard event, the current target will be the stage. For a mouse event, it's what was clicked on. That's why we created a variable to store what the current spr_box is.

Comment: Thank You so much. I've been struggling with this problem for days and now it works!